# I can't seem to get any application indicators to show up - why not?

Tags: indicator, package-management, python

I am trying to run a program that makes use of application indicators - but it isn't working. This could be because I am missing a package (I didn't use the Desktop Installer CD to install Ubuntu - I installed the core packages and then added others as needed). The application in question is written in Python.

Here is a simple Python script to check and see if app. indicators are working:

```
import appindicator
import gtk

appindicator.Indicator("test", "monitor", appindicator.CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS)
gtk.main()
```

Comment: Said script doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @jrg: Do you have `python-appindicator` and `python-gtk2` installed?

Comment: Yes, I do - both `python-appindicator` and `python-gtk2` are the newest versions.

Comment: Does the one here work? - http://www.jonobacon.org/2009/12/17/application-indicators-in-python/

Comment: @jrg: Yes, actually it does! (Now I'm confused...)

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question, since it's obvious your script is faulty. :P

Comment: Or you could post an answer saying he did it wrong and get credits for it! Decisions, decisions... ^^

Comment: @jrg: Well it's not really the script that I'm asking about - it's the application that won't work ([this one](https://launchpad.net/stackapplet)).

Comment: @GeorgeEdison OK, then I will remove my answer since it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I clicked through the commented one:

http://www.jonobacon.org/2009/12/17/application-indicators-in-python/

and found the original wiki:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Python_version

It appears that adding the menu (even an empty one with "ind.set_menu(gtk.Menu())") results in a status indicator appearing.  Is that the desired result?

```
import appindicator
import gtk
ind = appindicator.Indicator("test", "monitor", appindicator.CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS)
ind.set_status(appindicator.STATUS_ACTIVE)
ind.set_attention_icon("indicator-messages-new")
menu = gtk.Menu()
ind.set_menu(gtk.Menu())
gtk.main()
```

Comment: Yes, and adding a menu does indeed cause the indicator to work. Thank you for the answer.